# Google Maps/PlacePicker ios api - is there a way to get nearby places as a GMSplace list?

Tags: ios, swift, google-api

I'm using place picker to pick a location on a map. After that, I want to get a GMSPlace list of restaurants in a specific radius, centered around the picked location.

Is there any way to implement that using the Google iOS API?

```
@IBAction func pickPlace(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: nil)
    let placePicker = GMSPlacePickerViewController(config: config)

    placePicker.delegate = self
    present(placePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func placePicker(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController, didPick place: GMSPlace){

    self.pickedNameLabel.text = place.name
    self.pickedAddressLabel.text = place.formattedAddress?.components(separatedBy: ", ").joined(separator: "\n")

    viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func placePickerDidCancel(_ viewController: GMSPlacePickerViewController){
    viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to be using the Google Places API, and NOT Google Place Picket API

Answer (score 0):

In didPick delegate fetch the place lat long and pass it to :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670,151.1957&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Source:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/